# Code signing issues and crashes after attempting to set up Keychain sharing

Tags: macos, keychain

I'm working on an app for Mac OS that consists of three binaries:

1. The main app, to be installed in the Applications folder.
2. A widget (for OS X Yosemite)
3. A LoginItem that monitors some stuff in the background (daemon-like, always running)

All three binaries connect to a certain web service with the same OAuth token. The token is retrieved by the main app (on first run, after the user signed in to the service) and stored in the system's Keychain.

To make sure the other two parts of the app can also access the same token, I'm trying to set up Keychain sharing. In Apple's Developer Portal, I've created three App Store Provisioning profiles, one for each binary. All of them are signed with the same developer certificate ("`3rd Party Mac Developer Application`").

In this situation, none of the binaries will run on my development system, citing "Code Signature Invalid". Also, in the system console, taskgated writes this message: "`killed [app] because its use of the keychain-access-groups entitlement is not allowed (error code -67050)`".

It is worth nothing that in the capabilities page of each target in Xcode, the Keychain sharing capability was enabled without any error whatsoever.

How do I solve this issue? The only thing I've came up with is simply disabling Keychain sharing, but this will require the user to click (Always) Allow when running the widget for the first time.

Another solution would be to eliminate the keychain altogether, but storing a OAuth token in an unsafe place like `NSUserDefaults` is not the way to go. I can't find a secure alternative for the keychain, which I think would be the best solution if it works anyway.

Comment: hey Rachid, did you find any solution for this ?